# /proc/sys/net/core is empty

Tags: oracle-linux

While investigating a problem in a particular Oracle Linux server, I wanted to check the value for `wmem_max` and `wmem_default` but found out that this directory is empty. Is this normal? Does the OS assume a default value if there's no configuration defined for `wmem_max` or `wmem_default`?

Kernel version: `Linux 5.4.174-2-pve x86_64`

Comment: It makes sense to specify your kernel version and whether your using Oracle's kernel or build it yourself.

Comment: Added kernel info.

Comment: The pve kernel is not a standard OEL kernel. I would suggest contacting the [Proxmox](https://www.proxmox.com/) developers. The directory is not empty on OEL7 and OEL8 servers using the UEK or standard kernels.

Comment: Thanks. Deleted previous erroneous comment stating it is Oracle's kernel. Is it a problem that the directory is empty, though?

Comment: You need to consult with the people who built it. Most people here use standard kernels.

Comment: Could be already running in a container with a setup hiding these settings. This could be tested with (installing and using) `virt-what`.

Comment: "unprivileged container mode" reproducer as non-root on a normal host: `unshare -n -m -p -U -r -f -- sh -c 'mount -t proc proc /proc; ls /proc/sys/net/core'` (getting an empty result. root (thus without options `-U -r`) would have gotten a few entries, but most would have disappeared too). So my guess is OP's "system" is a container with all limitations that come with this.

Comment: Thanks, this could definitely be the case.